# JavaFX timer- threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, timer

Normally, this code has to update a `TableView`'s duration field in JavaFX, but somehow I can't get it to work. It works properly when I just use `newCli.durationProperty().setValue(Integer.ToString(seconds++));` but I can't get it to work this way, maybe I'm missing something simple, any help would be appreciated. I tried formatting text with `SimpleDateFormat` but ended up with the same outcome.

```
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        int seconds=0;
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                      int hr = seconds/3600;
                                      int rem = seconds%3600;
                                      int mn = rem/60;
                                      int sec = rem%60;
                                      String hrStr = (hr<10 ? "0" : "")+hr;
                                      String mnStr = (mn<10 ? "0" : "")+mn;
                                      String secStr = (sec<10 ? "0" : "")+sec;
                                      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                                      sb.append(hrStr+":"+mnStr+":"+secStr);
                                      newCli.durationProperty().setValue(sb.toString());
                                      seconds = seconds++;     
                                  }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Your `Platform.runLater Runnable` inside the `TimerTask` is not required. Just implement the `run` method of the `TimerTask` itself and bind your UI property to the property that you need to listen to from the `TimerTask`. And just `seconds++;`, not `seconds = seconds++;`

Comment: James_D it is the reference of a new client object, i don't think there is any problem at that part though. normally when you update an object's properties binded on javafx tableView, it is automatically updated on the table. as i stated above, if i just use unformatted integer value it works ok.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "new client object" is. Is it the model for your table view?

Comment: @ManoDestra The timer's `run` method is executed on a background thread. If the code in the run method is updating the UI, whether that happens via a binding or directly, then the update needs to be wrapped in `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: Note @ManoDestra's last point: `seconds = seconds++ ;` **will not change** the value of `seconds`. You mean just `seconds++ ; ` or `seconds = seconds + 1 ;`.

Comment: Possibly, yes. That would be one way of handling that scenario.

Comment: I'm assuming that `newCli.durationProperty().setValue(...)` updates the UI (though the OP is for some reason refusing to be clear about this point).

Comment: Yea, seconds=seconds++ seems to be the cause of the problem :( that was a really silly mistake of mine, thanks guys.

Comment: @James_D yea it updates the ui, i tried to explain but maybe i wasn't clear enough, thanks anyway.

Comment: FWIW I recommend using a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) (instead of a `Timer`) for this kind of functionality: it avoids the creation of a background thread and you don't need to use `Platform.runLater()` to update the UI.

Comment: @James_D thanks, i will check that out.